# Permissions on folder different to folder's items and subfolders

Tags: permissions

My Problem is that I need to create a data structure based on folders within a document library. 
e.g.

> DocLib >>(Folder) Package1 >> Item1,Item2,SubFolder1,...

There will be thousands of items within each package and I need to set permissions to hundreds of users.
But now my Problem ;) 
I want to set the different permission groups at package1 folder level to let the underlying items inherit from it "but" I need to make sure that the package folder itself has different permissions to make sure that the users cannot manipulate or delete it. 
How can I do it?! ;) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My current idea is it to create a subfolder on the Package1 folder, hide it and give it the permission groups. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I can think of two options:

1. Break inheritance on all files under the Package1 folder so that each file will have unique permissions. Perhaps this option is not practical, though, considering you say there will be potentially thousands of files under the Package1 folder.
2. Make all files under the Package1 folder inherit permissions from Package1. Develop an `ItemUpdating` event receiver for the document library and check if the Package1 folder was changed in any way. If so, cancel the change.

Comment: Thanks for you advices!!! 
I had the same ideas but as you already said option 1 is not really practically for me because of the number of items. The event receiver is not really an option for me because of the usability for the users. I can see already the comments of them why it first looks like you can change and why there is this fancy error message afterwards ;) 
I guess my way to go is to create subfolders with the initial structure for the projects and attach the permissions to them. 
My intention to post it here was to get new ideas :)